# live data observer triggered when another variable

Tags: android

sorry for my English
I just started learning android and I'm trying to make a library app that uses Room db, recView and fragments
in the app there are 3 lists, all books, already read and Wishlist - the already read and Wishlist are just books that its property isAlreadyRead is true
in the viewModel i created 3 lists members, one for each list

--Book class--

```
@Entity(tableName = "books_table")
data class Book(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int = 1,
val name: String,
val author: String,
val desc: String,
val imgUrl: String,
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")
val isAlreadyRead: Boolean = false,
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")
val isWishlist: Boolean = false
```

)

--repository--

```
val allBooks = bookDao.getAllBooks().asLiveData()
val alreadyReadBooks = bookDao.getAlreadyReadBooks().asLiveData()
val wishlistBooks = bookDao.getWishlistBooks().asLiveData()
```

--viewModel--

```
val allBooks = repository.allBooks
val alreadyReadBooks = repository.alreadyReadBooks
val wishlistBooks = repository.wishlistBooks
```

(the repository and viewModel is just the important section of the code, if you need the whole code i will update the question)

the problem mainly occurs when i delete an object, i added the ability to delete using swipe with ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback

```
private val itemTouchHelperCallback =
    object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            if (viewHolder !is BookRecViewAdapter.BookViewHolder) {
                return
            }
            bookViewModel.removeFromWishlistBooks(viewHolder.bookId)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

when i delete in the already books, the bookViewModel.alreadyReadBooks observer is being called, but i noticed that also the bookViewModel.allBooks observer is being called, here is the code of the observers

--observer code inside onViewCreated of the fragments--

```
bookViewModel.allBooks.observe(requireActivity(), Observer { allBooks ->
        Log.d("observer:", "show all books observer")
        // Update the cached copy of the allBooks in the adapter.
        allBooks?.let { adapter.books = it }
        if (allBooks.isNotEmpty()) {
            binding.listEmptyTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            binding.listEmptyTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    })
```

(the code for the already read fragment and the wishist fragment is the same just that i called bookViewModel.alreadyReadBooks)

it crashes the app because in the observer i also want to update the visibility of a textView which just say that the list if empty (so there will be no white screen with no information), but binding is null because the fragment is in the background (i think that is the reason)

if you need any more info or code say, first time writing in stack overflow
thanks in advance

BTW: if you have any advice for me i will be happy to hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using `requireActivity()` instead of `viewLifecycleOwner` when you observe the bookViewModel. If I didn't guess right, you should show us the code that you have in your `Fragment` class.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem.  
just to make sure i understand the cause, requireActivity takes the activity Lifecycle which is basically always (since it was my main activity) and was still on even when i went to the already read fragment.  
now, using the viewLifecycleOwner  i take the show all books fragment Lifecycle which is the correct one because when im in the already read fragment it wont be called.

Comment: @Pizza4Me So by registering with requireActivity() you were registered for updates  for as long as the activity lived, not for as long as the respective fragment lived. When your fragment got destroyed, the binding variable turned null, naturally. When allBooks LiveData changed, it notified the Observer that you subscribed using requireActivity(), because it was still alive, since the activity didn't die. But the fragment died. And the code inside the Observer was referencing the stuff inside the dead fragment.

Comment: @Pizza4Me I think you understood correctly.